# Finding the value of Inverse Trigonometric functions beyond their Real Domain

Tags: trigonometry, inverse

I wanted to ask how can we calculate the values of the inverse of trigonometric functions beyond their domain of definition, for example $\arcsin{2}$ beyond its domain of $-\frac{\pi}{2}<x<\frac{\pi}{2}$.
I tried to use the Euler form but did not get much. Thanks.

Comment: You should show how you attempted to solve the problem. Here is a Math Jax tutorial for properly displaying mathematical functions meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/.

Comment: You forgot to put dollar signs on both sides of your function but that does not matter right now. I am afraid I do not have the expertise to help with this question but I did find this website  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions. Make sure to scroll all the way down to "Extensions to the Complex Plane".

Comment: Let for a complex number $z$ $\sin{z} = 2$ now we can write using Euler form that $e^{iz} = \cos{z} + i\sin{z}$ where $i = \sqrt{-1}$ and $e^{-iz} = \cos{z} - i\sin{z}$ now from these two equations we can get $\sin{z} =$ $e^{iz}-e^{-iz} \over2i $ now we get a quadratic in $e^{iz}$ as $\sin{z} = 2$ on solving which we get $e^{iz} = 2i +\sqrt3i $  or $e^{iz} = 2i +\sqrt3 i$ ($i$ is not in under root) putting back values and with some calculations i got $z$ = $\pi\over2$ $-i ln(2+(and)- \sqrt3)$
I am unable to decide whether I can write $\arcsin2 = z$.

Comment: If there is another mistake please tell (no space to write in that comment) and ignore my previous comment it was by mistake

Comment: @AlexM. Perhaps you have an answer.

Comment: @NeeleshVij. this has to be usable for all complex $z$, not any value.  $z=2$ was just an example the OP wanted to see used

Comment: @Arbuja I can understand why he didn't post his attempt at the problem.  Going anywhere with it required much skill in the manipulations of trigonometric functions and complex-analysis, and without such, he probably wrote down his Euler form and stopped there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Neelesh Vij, he makes an interesting point.  I will do my best to explain.

We have as follows:$$\sin(z)=x, z=\arcsin(x)$$$$e^{iz}=\cos(z)+i\sin(z)$$$$e^{-iz} =\cos(-z)+i\sin(-z)=\cos(z)-i\sin(z)$$And we are trying to solve for an unknown z, given x.

Made clear, the last line has the equation $e^{-iz}=\cos(z)-i\sin(z)$.  This was found with trigonometric identities.

Now subtract the last two equations to get the following:$$e^{iz}-e^{-iz}=2i\sin(z)$$$$\sin(z)=\frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{2i}$$Recall from the very top that $\sin(z)=x$.$$x=\frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{2i}=\frac1{2i}e^{iz}-\frac1{2i}e^{-iz}$$Multiply both sides by $e^{iz}$ to get a solvable quadratic.$$xe^{iz}=\frac1{2i}e^{2iz}-\frac1{2i}\to0=\frac1{2i}e^{2iz}-xe^{iz}-\frac1{2i}$$We can now use quadratic formula to solve for $e^{iz}$.  If you are confused, try substituting $e^{iz}=y$.$$e^{iz}=\frac{x\pm\sqrt{x^2-1}}{\frac1i}=i(x\pm\sqrt{x^2-1})$$Now, solve for z.$$iz=\ln[i(x\pm\sqrt{x^2-1})]=\ln(i)+\ln[(x\pm\sqrt{x^2-1})]=\pi(\frac12+2in)+\ln[x\pm\sqrt{x^2-1}],n=\pm(0,1,2,3,4,\ldots)$$

We get a grand and wondrous solution:$$z=\frac{\pi(\frac12+2in)+\ln[x\pm\sqrt{x^2-1}]}i,n=\pm(0,1,2,3,4,\ldots)$$So for $x=2$, we can find $z=\arcsin(2)$.$$\arcsin(2)=\frac{\pi(\frac12+2in)+\ln[2\pm\sqrt{2^2-1}]} i,n=\pm(0,1,2,3,4,\ldots)$$

Lastly, take note that $\arcsin(x)=\arccos(x)-\frac{\pi}2\pm2\pi m, m=0,1,2,3,4,\ldots$ so that we have:$$\arccos(x)=\frac{\pi(\frac12+2in)+\ln[x\pm\sqrt{x^2-1}]}i+\frac{\pi}2\pm2\pi m, m=0,1,2,3,4,\ldots,n=\pm(0,1,2,3,4,\ldots)$$

Comment: Got it!! almost same how i did it thanks @simple art

Comment: XD  No problem man.  How did you do it though?  O.o  I'd like to see your attempt.

Comment: Consider a case $\arcsin2 =$ $\pi\over2  $ $- i\ln{2}$ where $i = \sqrt -1$ now $2= \sin(\pi/2 -i\ln2)$ so $\sin(\pi/2 -i\ln2)$ is equivalent to imaginary part of $e^{i\pi/2 + \ln2}$ which is $2e^{i\pi/2}$ which gives us imaginary part $=2$ and thus satisfies the equation but this solution was nowhere in your answer.. 
what to do !!

Comment: XD  I feel you man.  And to tell you the truth, I'm a (young) High School-er who hasn't learned Calculus (officially) or any complex-analysis except for the fact that $I=\sqrt{-1}$ (officially).  Amazingly, I've reached this point in my life through sheer perseverance of mathematics.

Comment: Good to see someone with deep love with maths. also i am in high school too so i can understand u :)

Comment: Lol.  There is practically no one who understands my passion.

Comment: Sorry if i hurt u but for now i wanna understand the problem @simple art.

Answer (score -1):

Let us start with the well known Euler form:$$e^{i\theta}=\cos\theta+i\sin\theta$$Now we solve for $cos\theta$.$$\cos\theta=e^{i\theta}-isin\theta$$Now take the $arccos$ of both sides.$$\theta=\arccos(e^{i\theta}-i\sin\theta)=\arccos[f(\theta)]$$Attempt to find the inverse of $f(\theta)$.$$f(\theta)=e^{i\theta}-i\sin\theta=x$$I do not have the skills to do this, if it is possible.  I will assume I have the answer to be $\theta=f^{-1}(x)$.  You would then substitute it up above.$$\theta=\arccos[f(\theta)]$$$$f^{-1}(x)=\arccos[f(f^{-1}(x))]=\arccos(x)$$

And that is your solution.

Comment: Look how lame this answer is in comparison to my other one.  I feel slightly ashamed...